# Can I use spread syntax on route?

Tags: node.js, express, server, backend

I want to get something like `/preview/folder1/folder2/file.arw` but make it dynamic because it's for a file browser, so using `/preview/:folder1/:folder2/:file` is very not dynamic.

I tried:

```js
  router.post("/openFile/:fileName", verifyTokenQuery, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    return res.sendFile(path.join(storagePath, req.body.data));
  });
```

But when using that for previewing images with `<img>`, I can't put it to POST mode

Comment: `router.get("/preview/*", ...)` allows you to access the file path as `req.url.substring(9)`.